# Double appearance of the same verb

Tags: repetition, synonyms

Below is the sentence in question, in which the same verb occurred twice with only one auxiliary between them:

> Most particles passed straight through, but those that were **deflected** were **deflected** quite significantly.

I am not fond of repetitions. Could you suggest a set word/phrase I can use in place of the second 'deflected'? Something kind of like the adjectival pronoun 'that of', or a dummy verb.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

> Most particles passed straight through, but those that did not were
>   deflected quite significantly.

Comment: Simple and elegant.

Answer (score 1):

What about reconstructing the sentence, as in:

> Most particles passed straight through, except some that were deflected significantly.

This could work because your sentence implies all the particles that were deflected, were deflected significantly.

Answer (score 1):

> Most particles passed straight through, but **the minority that didn't** were deflected quite significantly.

Comment: A less unredundant echo of McCaverty's answer.

Comment: `less unredundant` heh

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the original post -

> *Most particles passed straight through, but those that were deflected were deflected quite significantly* -

except that the author is not happy with the repetition of 'deflected'.  This 'fault' is easily remedied and the whole sentence made more concise  -

***Most particles passed straight through.  A few were deflected quite significantly.***

Comment: As a user with 10k rep, you should know ELU is looking for answers with a bit of explanation behind them... This answer has come up on the LQP review.

Answer (score -3):

Here is my edit:

> Most particles passed straight through, but those that were deflected **at all did so** quite significantly.

Even the insertion of 'at all' breaks up the sentence from the deflected-deflected crowd.

Comment: That doesn’t work at all. _Did so_ cannot be used as a dummy verb for a passive construction.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - You may be right, as you seem very sure.

Comment: Just. “... But those that were deflected, were so quite significantly.”